# Refresh data in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-post, refresh

I'm setting up an mailing application. Whenever a user loads the page for the first time I'm doing a POST to the database with the userId and date. 
After the POST is done I want to show those values in the view aswell.

So I have a constructor and inside I have this code:

```
requestService.acknowledgeRequest($stateParams['programId'], $stateParams['requestId'])
                .then(() => {

                });
```

How can I refresh the ng-binds on the page after the post is done?

Thanks!
Greets Brent.

Comment: Just update the binding variable

Answer (score 0):

If you are using normal ajax post request then you have to do

```
$scope.$apply()
```

or else You can use $http post request.